# Twisted wait for event in loop

Tags: python, twisted

I want to read and process some data from an external service. I ask the service if there is any data, if something was returned I process it and ask again (so data can be processed immediately when it's available) and otherwise I wait for a notification that data is available. This can be written as an infinite loop:

```
def loop(self):
    while True:
        data = yield self.get_data_nonblocking()
        if data is not None:
            yield self.process_data(data)
        else:
            yield self.data_available

def on_data_available(self):
    self.data_available.fire()
```

How can `data_available` be implemented here? It could be a Deferred but a Deferred cannot be reset, only recreated. Are there better options?

Can this loop be integrated into the Twisted event loop? I can read and process data right in `on_data_available` and write some code instead of the loop checking `get_data_nonblocking` but I feel like then I'll need some locks to make sure data is processed in the same order it arrives (the code above enforces it because it's the only place where it's processed). Is this a good idea at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the case of a TCP connection.  The receiver buffer for a TCP connection can either have data in it or not.  You can get that data, or get nothing, without blocking by using the non-blocking socket API:

```
data = socket.recv(1024)
if data:
    self.process_data(data)
```

You can wait for data to be available using `select()` (or any of the basically equivalent APIs):

```
socket.setblocking(False)
while True:
    data = socket.recv(1024)
    if data:
        self.process_data(data)
    else:
        select([socket], [], [])
```

Of these, only `select()` is **particularly** Twisted-unfriendly (though the Twisted idiom is certainly not to make your own `socket.recv` calls).  You could replace the `select` call with a Twisted-friendly version though (implement a `Protocol` with a `dataReceived` method that fires a `Deferred` - sort of like your `on_data_available` method - toss in some yields and make this whole thing an `inlineCallbacks` generator).

But though that's one way you can get data from a TCP connection, that's not the API that Twisted encourages you to use to do so.  Instead, the API is:

```
class SomeProtocol(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        # Your logic here
```

I don't see how your case is substantially different.  What if, instead of the loop you wrote, you did something like this:

```
class YourDataProcessor(object):
    def process_data(self, data):
        # Your logic here

class SomeDataGetter(object):
    def __init__(self, processor):
        self.processor = processor

    def on_available_data(self):
        data = self.get_data_nonblocking()
        if data is not None:
            self.processor.process_data(data)
```

Now there are no Deferreds at all (except perhaps in whatever implements `on_available_data` or `get_data_nonblocking` but I can't see that code).

If you leave this roughly as-is, you are guaranteed of in-ordered execution because Twisted is single-threaded (except in a couple places that are very clearly marked) and in a single-threaded program, an earlier call to `process_data` must complete before any later call to `process_data` could be made (excepting, of course, the case where `process_data` reentrantly invokes itself - but that's another story).

If you switch this back to using `inlineCallbacks` (or any equivalent "coroutine" flavored drink mix) then you are probably introducing the possibility of out-of-order execution.

For example, if `get_data_nonblocking` returns a `Deferred` and you write something like this:

```
    @inlineCallbacks
    def on_available_data(self):
        data = yield self.get_data_nonblocking()
        if data is not None:
            self.processor.process_data(data)
```

Then you have changed `on_available_data` to say that a context switch is allowed when calling `get_data_nonblocking`.  In this case, depending on your implementation of `get_data_nonblocking` and `on_available_data`, it's entirely possible that:

1. `on_available_data` is called
2. `get_data_nonblocking` is called and returns a `Deferred`
3. `on_available_data` tells execution to switch to another context (via `yield` / `inlineCallbacks`)
4. `on_available_data` is called again
5. `get_data_nonblocking` is called again and returns a `Deferred` (perhaps the same one!  perhaps a new one!  depends on how it's implement)
6. The second invocation of `on_available_data` tells execution to switch to another context (same reason)
7. The reactor spins around for a while and eventually an event arrives that causes the `Deferred` returned by the *second* invocation of `get_data_nonblocking` to fire.
8. Execution switches back to the *second* `on_available_data` frame
9. `process_data` is called with whatever data the *second* `get_data_nonblocking` call returned
10. Eventually the same things happen to the first set of objects and `process_data` is called again with whatever data the *first* `get_data_nonblocking` call returned

Now perhaps you've processed data out of order - again, this depends on more details of other parts of your system.

If so, you can always re-impose order.  There are a lot of different possible approaches to this.  Twisted itself doesn't come with any APIs that are explicitly in support of this operation so the solution involves writing some new code.  Here's one idea (untested) for an approach - a queue-like class that knows about object sequence numbers:

```
class SequencedQueue(object):
    """
    A queue-like type which guarantees objects come out of the queue in the order
    defined by a sequence number associated with the objects when they are put into
    the queue.

    Application code manages sequence number assignment so that sequence numbers don't
    have to have the same order as `put` calls on this type.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        # The sequence number of the object that should be given out
        # by the next call to `get`
        self._next_sequence = 0

        # The sequence number of the next result that needs to be provided.
        self._next_result = 0

        # A holding area for objects past _next_sequence
        self._queue = {}

        # A holding area 
        self._waiting = 

    def put(self, sequence, object):
        """
        Put an object into the queue at a particular point in the sequence.
        """
        if sequence < self._next_sequence:
            # Programming error.  The sequence number
            # of the object being put has already been used.
            raise ...

        self._queue[sequence] = object
        self._check_waiters()

    def get(self):
        """
        Get an object from the queue which has the next sequence number
        following whatever was previously gotten.
        """
        result = self._waiters[self._next_sequence] = Deferred()
        self._next_sequence += 1
        self._check_waiters()
        return result

    def _check_waiters(self):
        """
        Find any Deferreds previously given out by get calls which can now be given
        their results and give them to them.
        """
        while True:
            seq = self._next_result
            if seq in self._queue and seq in self._waiting:
                self._next_result += 1
                # XXX Probably a re-entrancy bug here.  If a callback calls back in to
                # put then this loop might run recursively
                self._waiting.pop(seq).callback(self._queue.pop(seq))
            else:
                break
```

The expected behavior (modulo any bugs I accidentally added) is something like:

```
q = SequencedQueue()
d1 = q.get()
d2 = q.get()
# Nothing in particular happens
q.put(1, "second result")
# d1 fires with "first result" and afterwards d2 fires with "second result"
q.put(0, "first result")
```

Using this, just make sure you assign sequence numbers in the order you want data dispatched rather than the order it actually shows up somewhere.  For example:

```
    @inlineCallbacks
    def on_available_data(self):
        sequence = self._process_order
        data = yield self.get_data_nonblocking()
        if data is not None:
            self._process_order += 1
            self.sequenced_queue.put(sequence, data)
```

Elsewhere, some code can consume the queue sort of like:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def queue_consumer(self):
    while True:
        yield self.process_data(yield self.sequenced_queue.get())
```

Comment: Unfortunately `get_data_nonblocking()` is a third-party library function that returns a Deferred (that fires when server responds).

Comment: That's not inherently unfortunate.  It just means you need to add some logic to impose ordering.